# ansible vmware windows server

Tags: ansible, vmware, ipconfig

I am trying to execute my ansible playbook to launch VMware-windows-server with IP settings, but VM is getting launched but without IP settings.

after executing the playbook am not getting any errors and its shows changes also done, but when i checked in Vmware environment IP is not reflecting.

tried all possible ways, can anyone help me out on this.
thanks

here is my playbook :

```
---
- hosts: vm-windows-server2012
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars_files:
      - group_vars/vm-windows-server2012
  tasks:
  - name: "PROVISION | Create Windows server 2012 from template"
    vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: false
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
      name: "{{ guest_name }}"
      folder: "{{ folder }}"
      template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
      state: poweredon
      esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_host }}"
      hardware:
        num_cpus: "{{ cpu }}"
        memory_mb: "{{ mem_mb }}"
      disk:
        - size_gb: "{{ disk }}"
          type: thin
          datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
    register: new_vm
  - name: Wait for VMware tools to become available
    vmware_guest_tools_wait:
       hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
       username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
       password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
       validate_certs: False
       name: "{{ vm_name }}"
       folder: "/{{ datacenter }}/vm/{{ folder }}"
  - name: "IP configuration"
    local_action:
       module: vmware_vm_shell
       hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
       username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
       password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
       datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
       vm_id: "{{ vm_name }}"
       vm_username: "{{ v_username }}"
       vm_password: "{{ v_password }}"
       vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
       vm_shell_args: 'netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0 2" static 10.193.34.250 255.255.255.192 10.193.34.193'
       vm_shell_cwd: 'C:\Users\Administrator'
       validate_certs: False
```

Comment: added vmware_guest_tools_wait module and ran the playbook , but results are same . no IP is assigning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you have to wait for the VMWare Tools to be active on the VM in order to use `vmware_vm_shell`.

Use this before your `vmware_vm_shell`:

```
  - name: Wait for VMware tools to become available
    vmware_guest_tools_wait:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      validate_certs: False
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      folder: "/{{ vcenter_datacenter }}/vm/{{ default_vm_folder }}"

   - name: Change IP Address for Windows Machine
      vmware_vm_shell:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: False
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        folder: "/{{ datacenter }}/vm/{{ folder }}"
        vm_id: "{{ vm_name }}"
        vm_username: "{{ v_username }}"
        vm_password: "{{ v_password }}"
        vm_shell: netsh.exe
        vm_shell_args: ' interface ip set address name="Ethernet0 2" static 10.193.34.250 255.255.255.192 10.193.34.193'
        vm_shell_cwd: "C:\\Windows\\System32"

    - name: Change DNS for Windows Machine
      vmware_vm_shell:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: False
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        folder: "/{{ datacenter }}/vm/{{ folder }}"
        vm_id: "{{ vm_name }}"
        vm_username: "{{ v_username }}"
        vm_password: "{{ v_password }}"
        vm_shell       : netsh.exe
        vm_shell_args  : ' interface ip set dns name="Ethernet0 2" static 8.8.8.8'
        vm_shell_cwd   : "C:\\Windows\\System32"

    - name: Wait until the ipaddress of machine is ready
      wait_for:
        port: 5986
        delay: 20
        state: started
        host: "10.193.34.250"
```

Comment: Hi,as you said i have modified the script and added the vmware_guest_tools_wait module, even though the result is same , IP is not reflecting in my vmware environment. can you please help me out on this.

Comment: instead of assigning my actual IP its assigning some apipa address in the vmware.not sure where the problem exactly

Comment: can anyone please help me out on the above issue ?

Comment: I have modified my answer with full code. That is working for me. Please confirm